# UITextView at the bottom of the view

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

As a new MonoToucher, I have a question which I'm struggling for a while now:
In some cases in my app I need to display a `UITextView` with a button to its right, at the bottom of the screen.

Basically, I would like to manage some kind of discussion feed in which when the user navigate to a specific discussion he gets the related posts as a list and have a multi-line text input at the bottom of the list with a 'Post' button to the right.
Touching that `textView` should show the keyboard for input, and the height of the `textView` should be related to the data entered.
This is the same behavior as we have when we want to write a new Text Message in iPhone, or a post in Facebook.

Another requirement is, that when the user scrolls the posts list, that input (with the button) should not move.

I tried creating a `UIToolBar` with `UITextView` and a `UIButton`, but I can't make it work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the BubbleCell sample, it does exactly what you want in C#:

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/BubbleCell

Comment: The question is for UITextView. Not for c#.